# Using "for" variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a script that will receive a .txt file and a path as arguments.
The .txt file contains names of files, which I need to concatenate with the path.

File contains :

```
example1.txt
example2.txt
```

The path is :

```
C:\test
```

The output should be :

```
C:\test\example1.txt
C:\test\example2.txt
```

The problem comes when I try to use the "i" variable from the for loop in order to concatenate the strings:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=%~1
set path=%2
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%file%) do ( 
echo %%i    rem this displays the line correctly
set "line=%path%\%%i"    rem this doesn't work
echo %line% )
```

What am I supposed to do there in order to get it to work as described above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Regardless of your question and answer being a duplicate, there is no reason to the value of your path variable and the `FOR` variable to another environmental variable.  You can just use both directly with whatever command needs to use them

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The problem was in how the line variable was echoed.

This is the modified code :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=%~1
set path=%2
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%file%) do ( 
echo %%i    rem this displays the line correctly
set "line=%path%\%%i"    rem this doesn't work
echo !line! )
```

When echoing "line", it's supposed to be done with ! instead of %

Comment: Do not create a new veriable named `path`, it will overwrite the very important system variable, which already has that name.